# AWS EC2 publickey all of sudden denied

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, public-key

Hi my AWS EC2 public key has all of a sudden been denied.

I have checked the key against the instance and I am using the right one.

I have checked port 22 is accessible through my security group and that looks good to.

I have not made any changes in aws and my web server on the instance is working fine so I know the instance is available to connect to.

Is it possible that my key has been tampered with somehow.

This is the command that I am using to access my debian instance which has been 'sshing' fine up till now.

```
ssh -o "ServerAliveInterval 180" -i key.pem admin@xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

many thanks Jose

### EDIT

Here is the verbose output:

```
 $ ssh -v -o "ServerAliveInterval 180" -i /Users/Jose/Workspace/build/prod-key.pem admin@52.51.xx.14


OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.51.xx.14 [52.51.xx.14] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Jose/Workspace/build/prod-key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Jose/Workspace/build/prod-key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 52.51.xx.14:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ZKUAyMwCyvgy42SSYy8+hNsYKz13m0u0Uwp1RvXSAac
debug1: Host '52.51.xx.14' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Jose/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Jose/Workspace/build/prod-key.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Can you provide the verbose output with an error?

Comment: Have you checked ip address you are using is correct ?
got to your instance lists and select instance that you want to connect then click on connect button, where you can check example e.g

ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@xxxx.amazonaws.com

Comment: Such a pain in my ass, this is in production, no one has our key and I've seen AWS do things like this all the time. Always related to S3. Super ***ing annoying when we have thousands of users.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible that my key has been tampered with somehow?

Yes, it always possible and you can't rule it out, however is it likely to be the case, I would doubt it. (Of course it depends what are doing with your server).

Most of the time it will be some service or some configuration which has been change but not applied until later i.e. server restart or other automatic process restart.

Anyway [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/772187/all-of-a-sudden-cant-connect-to-aws-ec2-instance-server-unexpectedly-closed-ne/) is very similar ticket to yours. Where I have provided how you can investigate very same issue.

Assuming that you don't have off site logging, any remote configuration management software (Puppet, Ansibel, Cheef et.c) or another user you can try to ssh as.

The only option to investigate this further in my opinion would be (Assuming that you don't want to shut down the server):

1. Take snapshot of the root volume of your affected instance.
2. Create a volume out of the snapshot.
3. Mount the new volume on a good working instance.
4. Go to the mounted volume and investigate.

Comment: Thank you MichalT, much appreciated I will investigate further

Comment: Let me know if you find what was causing this ;)

Comment: This is a little embarrassing, but I feel compelled to share what I found out with my server since the 4 steps above led to the discovery. I ran a remote command on my server that changed the owner of all the files in my home directory to `www-data`. Like this `ssh -t ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx 'sudo chown -R www-data:www-data'`. Oops